# User-defined constructor overload not being parameter-matched to the overload with the argument's superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, overloading

Following the code-snippet below, I attempt to pass a `Boo<int>` instance through the `Boo<T>::Boo(Foo const &)` constructor overload, which I cannot manage to do.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo { };

template <typename T>
struct Boo : public Foo
{
    // Boo(Boo<T> const &) = delete; // Leaves (2) without a constructor 

    Boo()            { std::cout << "Beep " << sizeof(T) << std::endl; }
    Boo(Foo const &) { std::cout << "Boop " << sizeof(T) << std::endl; }
};

void fun(Foo const &) { }

int main()
{
    Boo<int> x;       // (1) Output: Beep 4
    Boo<int> y(x);    // (2) Output:
    Boo<double> z(x); // (3) Output: Boop 8
    fun(x);           // (4) Compiles

    return 0;
}
```

In the code-snippet I tried to write a simplistic scenario which can be copy-pasted to play around with, if need be.

1. At (1), we generate a `Boo<int>` instance `x`, which uses the `Boo<T>::Boo()` constructor overload.
2. At (2), we pass instance `x` to the constructor of instance `y`, which uses the implicitly defined copy constructor `Boo<T>::Boo(Boo<T> const &)`. Hence, we do not receive an output message.
3. At (3), we pass instance `x` to the constructor of instance `z`, which uses the `Boo<T>::Boo(Foo const &)` constructor overload.
4. At (4), we confirm that `Boo<int>` can be implicitly converted to `Foo const &` by the compiler and passed into the `fun(Foo const &)` function.

**Question:** How can I get (2) to go through the same constructor as (3) does, and why does it not already do that?

If anyone can see what I have missed, I would much appreciate it, were it pointed out to me.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why do you want 2 to do the same thing as 3?  The implicit copy constructor is an exact match in 2 so it is going to be preferred.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thank you, this will definitely be in hand in the future. @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you for the fix. @NathanOliver I agree with you, although in my case it is preferred that all `Boo<T>` regardless of `T`, to go through the same constructor as (3). You mention that it is an "exact match," which I cannot deny, but it is also why I added the commented line of code which `delete`s the implicitly defined constructor in an effort to force (2) to behave as (3), but instead (2) cannot match any of the available constructors. The `fun` function is there to demonstrate that it does match, though.

Comment: So, you should rely on static polymorphism (here, template based) instead of runtime polymorphism (reference like you wrote). Why not? `template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_assignable<typename Foo>, T>::value> Boo(T const &)` then continue your code

Comment: @user9335240 Thank you for your comment. I argue your suggestion is a possible solution, depending on the desired approach. Feel free to post it as an alternative solution in the answers section. I was personally attempting to identify whether there is a way to use the run-time polymorphism efficiently to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a delegating constructor:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Boo : public Foo
{
    Boo(Boo<T> const & arg) : Boo(static_cast<Foo const&>(arg)) {};

    Boo()            { std::cout << "Beep " << sizeof(T) << std::endl; }
    Boo(Foo const &) { std::cout << "Boop " << sizeof(T) << std::endl; }
};
```

The reason this fixes it is that there is no longer an implicit copy constructor, which would have been a better match than casting to `Foo const&` and using constructor `Boo<T>::Boo(Foo const&)`, and calls it manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is the implementation I had gone with by the time I was writing my question, but I was not sure whether it was the most robust or efficient one, code-wise. Your explanation has given me clarity and the confidence to go on with this approach. If you somehow know or can figure out why deleting the implicit copy constructor does not force the compiler to choose the `Boo<T>::Boo(Foo const &)` constructor based on its polymorphism, please do edit your answer or comment below. Perhaps it is simply not programmed to do so.

Comment: @HelloWorld A deleted function is still a definition, so `Boo<T>::Boo(Boo<T> const&)` would still be chosen. But since it is a deleted function, it will be a compile time error (Which is the point of deleted functions). There's nothing inefficient about this solution, as long as you compile with some optimisation.

Comment: Perfect, you have covered all my concerns. From my perspective, this answer is a complete one. Thank you, Artyer.